# SOAP project with Spring MVC, maven, weblogic

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, soap, weblogic-10.x

I am new to Spring MVC and Web Services. I want to create SOAP services using Spring MVC, Maven and deploy it in weblogic. I want it from scratch. I know this platform is not to ask this type of question but I did not get response in other discussion forum. Please give me some reference link here so that I can go through that.

Answer (score 0):

This has everything you need to get started: http://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/